# Get property from a Func<>

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to return the property that has been passed to a Func<> so I can then use this property with a DbSet. See below code for this.

Calling code:
`_exampleRepository.CountByField(x => x.Status)`

Receiving method in a generic repository:

```
        public Dictionary<string, int> CountByField(Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> field)
        {
            var whichField = ((MemberExpression) field.Body).Member.Name;
            var data = _dbSet.Select(x => whichField).GroupBy(y => y);

            var returnData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                returnData.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
            }

            return returnData;
        }
```

At the moment I'm able to return the name of the property passed, but I need to use the actual property instead to complete the _dbSet.Select() line properly.

Any ideas? I feel like I'm not a million miles away! Just need a point in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: what is TEntity?

Comment: Just pass `field` directly into `Select`. It already does the thing you want it to do.

Comment: Also, you probably want to do `.Select(group => new { Key = group.Key, Count = group.Count() }).ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Count);` rather than looping over the data on client side and getting the count for each group separately.

Comment: @Luaan I tried passing "field" to begin with, but I get this error: "The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

Comment: @nebula099 Not `x => field`, just `_dbSet.Select(field)`. `field` is already a lambda expression.

Comment: @Luaan Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things; your `field` argument is already fit to be passed directly to `Select` :) You should probably also aggregate the data in the query, rather than issuing a new query for each group you get:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> CountByField(Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> field)
  =>
     _dbSet
       .Select(field)
       .GroupBy(i => i)
       .Select(i => new { Key = i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
       .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Count);
```

Comment: @Fabio `ToDictionary` works with the enumerable, i.e. after the query is executed. The `Count()` isn't really there anymore.